# Testing node js module with injected dependecy

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon

I am java, c# programmer with more than 10 years experience. Now I have to write some code in js and really, I feel like Alice in Wonderland....

I have myModule.js :

```
module.exports = function (logger) {
return {
    read: function (param) {
        ......
        logger.eror(....)
    },

    write: function (param) {
        ......
        logger.info(....)
    }
};
```

}

The logger.js, (legacy code, I cannot change it) looks similar:

```
module.exports = function(some_settings){
 return {
    info: function () {
        ......
    },

    error: function () {
        ......
    }
};
}
```

Important thing: logger is not included to myModule by require("logger") but injected in some "global" index.js file which looks like:

```
var settings = require("../someSettings.js")();
var logger = require("../logger.js")(settings);
var myModule = require("../myModule .js")(logger);
```

Now I want to write UT for myModule in mocha. So I want to mock logger. And I face the wall.
I tried proxyquire but this is not good solutions because logger is not included to myModule by require.
I tried sinon stub and mock e.g.:

```
var logger = require("logger.js");
var loggerMock = sinon.mock(logger);
var myModule= require("myModule.js")(loggerMock);
```

Or:

```
var logger = require("logger.js");
var loggerStub = sinon.stub(logger, "info", function() {return ....});
var myModule= require("myModule.js")(loggerStub);
```

But I still have some errors like : 
"Attempted to wrap undefined property error as function"...

Please, be my white rabbit in this javascript  freeky world...

Answer (score 0):

When you are testing your module, you can use a **fake object** for your logger object, i.e.:

```
const logger = {info: noop, error: noop, debug:...};
function noop() {}
```

or well create a **mock object** with [`sinonjs`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sinon) if you prefer create it programatically and use spy features.

Then, you can inject it wrapping your module definition in a closure (as you posted):

```
# myModule.js:

module.exports = (dep1, dep2, ...) => {
  // module definition
}
```

Or use [`rewire`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rewire) package, to "inject" module scoped dependencies (it works only for local-vars, and not need to create a closure in your module):

```
# myModuleTest    

myModule = rewire('./myModule');
myModule.__set__('logger', { /* fake logger */ });
```